# How to structure of a Symfony 2 application to support multiple applications?

Tags: symfony

**Background**

We are planning to migrate our current code to a Symfony2 project.

In our case, each application is considered to be a country where we operate. As such:

- Each application has a unique top-level domain.
- Each application will have the same subdomains.
- Each application has its own database. The database structure for each application is the same.
- Applications will share the same business logic. Any differences in business logic will be abstracted into a configuration file. There should be a base configuration file that applications can override with application-specific configurations.
- Applications will share most of the templates, but there may be application-specific templates too.

**Possible approaches**

1. **Multiple repos**

   - Each application would be a Symfony2 project by itself.
   - All development would take place in bundles, each application loading the same bundles thru composer.
   - This approach would make development quite cumbersome. Ideally I would like to test any changes in all countries without running composer etc.
2. **Multiple apps within a single repo with multiple Kernels**

   - Each application would have its own app in the `app/` folder as suggested in [here](http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2).
   - Duplicating the whole app folder seems a bit hackish. Not sure if this is a recommended practice?
3. **Modify Symfony2 to support multiple applications**

   - Modify the Symfony2 Kernel/Console/Whatever to support multiple applications.
   - Are there any existing bundles/examples already doing this?
4. **[Your idea here]**

   - Are there any other possible approaches?

**Question**

What would be the best approach to add support for multiple applications in Symfony2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a fine approach but if you find you are sharing a lot of code...
2. The creator of Symfony2 does not recommend this practice. If you need multiple kernels, you most likely need multiple projects. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony-devs/yneojUuFiqw/sZ8BZrzFLbwJ
3. IDK
4. For a project I have built the changes come from a $_GET parameter. What I do is, I have a primary project bundle that handles the common functionality and references the app/view for basic layout. Inside the "core" functionality, I created a controller and use it as a service so that all my application-specific bundles can use it at any point. Then I create a Symfony2 extension for each of my application-specific config definitions so that each application can have yml configs while keeping high-level config in app/config/config.yml. An advantage of this is that in the CoreBundle's controller I can create generic page routes and render like:

   `$this->render('Name'.$project.'Bundle:index.html.twig', array('params' => $params));`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. We decided to go with your approach. Our configs currently reside in our bundles. The extension then decides which config to load based on the country (i.e. application). We had to modify the AppKernel and Console to be aware of multiple applications.